Is there a musical term for the "swinging" chord sequences in songs like Thomas the Tank Engine's intro?
I'm not trained in any particular musical discipline so my terminology will be awry here. I'm interested if there's a term for the "back and forth" swinging chord pattern that you can hear in the main theme tune for Thomas the Tank Engine, in the left hand piano chords? You also hear this sort of pattern in the left hand of Joplin's The Entertainer.
Thomas the Tank Engine: 


You can hear a similar "bouncing" melody in this Bollywood song: 


Maybe "The Entertainer" isn't the best example, but kind of has a bouncing melody on the left-hand here: 



Sure, I've added some links

It's a sort of stride piano playing, where in its most simplified version, there's bass on 1 and 3, with the appropriate chords on 2 and 4.
